# How to load pictures faster with http.server?

Tags: python, server

For developpement purpose, I'm using `http.server` to serve a local website.

A webpage uses a lot of locally hosted pictures (several MBs). When I serve it with `python -m http.server`, the page needs several seconds to load.

If I reload the same page, the page refreshes with the same delay than the first time.
My guess is that caching doesn't seem to happen then?

How can I load pictures faster with `http.server`?

Comment: Use a full featured web server and set the appropriate header if that is not done by the server already.

Comment: that's what I'm reduced to finally. The simple `http.server` is probably "too" simplistic...